# Switch Number Input Spinners

Tags: html, input

Is there any way to flip the functionality of the number input spinners? For example, currently pushing the up arrow on a number input spinner will increase the field value and pushing the down arrow decreases the value. Can I switch them, like pushing the up arrow will decrease the field value? (I am making a priority list for those curious, so it is intuitive to push the up arrow to increase priority, a lower value).

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would make me pause and think, its not intuitive imo ...

Comment: Besides the intuitive part, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am facing the same problem...